# NSCFArray not acting as NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I'm trying to save data to and XML file on Iphone. For that, I load the wholeXML, add new data and the save it again. The problem arises when i try to store the new data, my

```
 [mArray addObject:newData];
```

methods crashes, as mArray is not a NSMutableArray, instead, it is a NSCFArray even if I applied a mutableCopy method to it.
As I understand, a NSCFArray is a toll-free bridging to an NSArray, so I can't understand why the mutablyCopy method is not working.
Any idea??

```
NSMutableDictionary *wholeXML = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
wholeXML = xmlData;

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
array = [wholeXML objectForKey:@"Key"];
mArray = [a mutableCopy];
```

Comment: where does `a` come from that gets the `mutableCopy` message call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSCFArray` is a private subclass that gets instantiated when you do things with `NSArray` factory methods or initializers. You're doing too many initializations. Try this simplified version:

```
NSMutableDictionary *wholeXML = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:xmlData];
NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[wholeXML valueForKey:@"Key"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

NSCFArray is the concrete class for both NSMutableArray and NSArray. It sounds like you are simply mistaken about what kind of array you have. Since the code you posted is obviously not your real code (it won't even compile, and wouldn't exhibit the problem even if it did), it's impossible to tell at what point your program is assigning an immutable array to the variable. But that's what it sounds like is happening.

I will say (and please don't take this as a personal criticism — it's just an observation) that the code you posted suggests you don't have a strong grasp on how classes and object identity work. That's probably the root cause here.

All three of your variables you initialize with `[[Something alloc] init]`, but then you immediately throw away the object and replace it with something else. This means the original object (NSMutableArray in this case) just gets leaked and the variable now contains the new object you have assigned. If that new object isn't an NSMutableArray, it won't magically be turned into one just because that's what the variable held before.

Comment: You are right, I am very confused on what is happening. Thank you for the explanation! It helped me to have a better grasp of what is happening!